# Storing and comparing against objects from a database

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app that loads in a list of students to display in a list based activity. There are two components to the app. There is a server which responds via xml with the list of current active students and a database on the app end which stores theses students with some details (name,age etc). I would like a way to sync these two data sources. When the app starts, I would like to check against the xml to see if students on the server were added/deleted and update the db accordingly.

I would be parsing the xml list into a student object at login. Is there any way to store/retrieve an entire object into an android supported db so I can do a direct comparison to see what to update/delete? It would end up being something like

```
if (serverStudent[0].name == dbStudent[0].name)
   //overwrite dbStudent object with serverStudent fields
```

What is the most efficient/lightweight way to achieve object persistance and then comparison  in Android?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Do you already have a database? How many records would there be? Do they have an updated timestamp? Why not just store the xml itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method I have used in the past:

Anytime an object in the database is changed, use a timestamp column to store that time. When the app connects on startup, simply check each timestamp in the app db against the timestamp in the server db for each object. If the timestamps match, do nothing. If the timestamps don't match, retrieve the updated record from the server. Make sure you're using a detail enough timestamp (usually down to milli- or micro- seconds).

The nice thing about timestamps is that if you don't want the server data to override the app data, you could look at which is newer and keep that object if they've both been edited. Just adding some additional thoughts!

Comment: Good answer. Also have on your server a service that lists (and consolidates) all updates since any given timestamp. That way you can connect and immediately get the delta between the two systems.

Comment: True! You could simply store ONE timestamp per user that gets updated anytime a record they've "checked out" is updated. Then you only test 1 timestamp each time and if it doesn't match, simply fetch the records with newer timestamps!

Comment: Timestamps can be troublesome though, if you have to account for time zones.  You could use a GUID instead.

Comment: Anytime you're working with date/time stamps, you need to be able to account for timezones. GUID can work as well since it incorporates timestamps with some unique identifier from the system (I forget exactly what it uses) but may also be able to help you identify which system edited it last (server or app)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
public class StudentRecord {
    Vector<StudentData> studentDatas;
    public StudentRecord()
    {
        studentDatas = new Vector<StudentData>();
    }
    public Vector<StudentData> getRecords() {
        return studentDatas;
    }
    public void setRecords(Vector<StudentData> records) {
        this.studentDatas = records;
    }

    public class StudentData
    {
        String name,Rollno;

        public String getRollno() {
            return Rollno;
        }

        public void setRollno(String rollno) {
            Rollno = rollno;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

}
```

When you get the vector object `studentDatas` you can do something like this -

```
for(Object object : record.getRecords())
        {
            data = (StudentData)object;
            data.getRollno();
            data.getName();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out these libraries:
http://www.datadroidlib.com/
https://github.com/octo-online/robospice
I believe both offer solutions for your situation.

Or you can roll your own solution... Basically you will want to create a service or asynctask to do the syncing, in your student object you can create a constructor that you can pass an id  to and have it pull the appropriate record from your local db then make a comparison method that will update if newer information is available.

Comment: Link-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/166749). Can you expand on this answer at all to make it more helpful?

Comment: @PaulBellora Thank you as I did not know that. I added more information but the op seems to understand what he needs to do, just looking for the best way to do it. These libraries offer full solutions from end to end for this specific task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood your question correctly.But as far as i understand i would do something like this.

- In server side send send Json array which holds json student objects.
- In android side create similer Student class and override equals
  method as you want.
- Then for each student check with equals method whether they are
  equals or not and take action accordingly.
- If you want to make faster search in students object array then apply
  hash map instead of arrays.

Comment: the issue is that right now i would have to reconstruct the student object once i have a query returned from my db in order to compare against the student object i just created from the json data i got back. Doesnt that seem excessive? I am looking for a better solution in the persistance of the student in the db so it doesnt have to be forced into an object once retrieved from the db for the comparison